# Javascript class, object, new

Tags: javascript

I have written following code

1.

```
function Car() {
  this.make = "BMW"
}

var x = new Car().make
alert(x)
```

Result: shown alert BMW

2.

```
function Car() {
  this.make = "BMW"
}

var x = Car().make //removed new keyword
alert(x)
```

Result: did not show alert BMW. Error in console "Cannot read property 'make' of undefined"

3.

```
function Car() {
  this.make = "BMW"
  return this      //added return
}

var x = Car().make //removed new keyword
alert(x)
```

Result: shown alert BMW

Can anybody explain, what exactly happening, when I return 'this' ...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `Car()` (without the `new` operator), inside the function, `this` refers to the global context (e.g., `window` if you are in a browser). When you `return this;`, you are returning the global object. You should also find that your function set the `make` property of the global object to `"BMW"` (that is, `alert(Car().make)` followed by `alert(make)` should alert the same thing twice. Without `return this;` the default return value from a function is `undefined`.

When you use the `new` operator, a new object is created and bound to `this` inside the function while it is executing. The `new` operator return whatever the constructor returns, or the new object if the construction does not return anything. For more info about this, see [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new).